# How to get tinyMCE to fake a text/html toggle to enable live update change

Tags: javascript, tinymce, execcommand

The code below responds to a button click on the tinyMCE editor toolbar and adds the <--nextpage--> tag into the source markup at the caret position.

This works great.

However, until I click over to the source view, then back to visual, there's no way to tell that the placeholder got inserted.

Once I click over to text view, then back to wysiwyg I can then see the wysiwyg placeholder graphic that wordpress inserts to denote the <--nextpage--> element in the content.

I notice that when I click the "Insert More Tag" button, the WordPress editor somehow updates the tinyMCE editor view to show the "more tag" placeholder graphic (without requiring the user to toggle views).

Perhaps there is an execCommand I can call in my function below to do the same? the mceRepaint is not doing it.

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.nextpage', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('nextpage', {
                title : 'Next Page Button',
                image : url+'/images/btn_nextpage.png',
                onclick : function() {
                    var prompt_text = "<!--nextpage-->";
                    var caret = "caret_pos_holder";
                    var insert = prompt_text + "<span id="+caret+"></span>";
                    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, insert);
                    ed.selection.select(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //select the span
                    ed.dom.remove(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //remove the span
                    ed.execCommand("mceRepaint"); //DOES NOT REFRESH THE LIVE VIEW

                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('nextpage', tinymce.plugins.nextpage);
})();
```

Update: I'm trying to use Chrome's dev tools to trace what's happening when I click the WordPress "Insert More Tag" button, but its not showing me anything. I'd like to have that information exposed so that I can see what's happening under the hood when that button is clicked to get the desired results.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it to work by adding this command after my insert statement:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
```

(instead of the mceRepaint statement)